# Where is the zipcloak puts the temporary file by default?

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, file-permissions

When I use zipcloak to encrypt an existed zip file, I got an error like this:

`zipcloak error: Permission denied
zipcloak error: Temporary file failure (ziC8mO6F)`

The command I executed:

`/usr/local/bin/zipcloak /Library/WebServer/foo.zip`

I'm sure I've set the permission of /Library/WebServer to 777, but it seems like zipcloak create the temporary file in a different place.

By the way when I specify the temporary path by -b option of zipcloak, it's worked.

`/usr/local/bin/zipcloak -b /Library/WebServer/ /Library/WebServer/foo.zip`

The -b option:
`-b Use  the specified path for the temporary zip archive`

Answer (score 0):

It tries to open a temporary file in the current directory.

Comment: That is what I thought.. But is that different from the directory I specified?

Comment: @kinopyo: Actually, it appears to create it in the destination directory. Can you reproduce this error if you try it on a copy of the file in a different directory?